# How can i pass a variable from windows forms project to a dll project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a solution i have two projects one is dll project and thr second is windows forms.
In the windows forms project in form1 i can call methods from the dll project for example:

In form1 top:

```
Capture.Hook.DX11.DXOverlayEngine overlayengine;
```

In constructor:

```
overlayengine = new Capture.Hook.DX11.DXOverlayEngine();
```

And then in the constructor i can make:

```
overlayengine.Draw();
```

In the project dll in the Draw() method there are two lines that draw:

```
_spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y, textElement.Text, textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
                            _spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y + 25,
                                              DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"),textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
```

This is what i did now:

In the dll project(library type project) i added in top:

```
public bool DrawEnabled { get; set; }
```

Then inside the Draw() method i did:

```
if (DrawEnabled == true)
                            {
                                _spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y, textElement.Text, textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
                                _spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y + 25,
                                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"), textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
                            }
```

Then in form1 i did at top:

```
Capture.Hook.DX11.DXOverlayEngine overlayengine;
```

Then in form1 constructor:

```
overlayengine = new Capture.Hook.DX11.DXOverlayEngine();
overlayengine.DrawEnabled = false;
```

Then in a button click event in form1 i did:

```
void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            overlayengine.DrawEnabled = true;
        }
```

I used a breakpoint and it's getting and doing overlayengine.DrawEnabled = true; but i don't see the drawings anywhere when i press the key.

what's wrong ?

Comment: does the Constructor of the Dll have any overloads..? also can you view the dll in the object browser to quickly see the signature of any of the internal methods..?

Comment: When you say dll project you mean you do not have the source just a compiled dll correct? If so the method you are trying to call should have a bool value that you need to pass it.

Comment: No i have both sources of the dll project by dll i mean library type project that create dll that you can't run by it self. But i have the source code of both. The problem is that Draw() is beign called from some places in the dll project i can't realy track it and the draw lines are being called each second or saw like a timer. So i can't just call it from form1 and decide on form if to call it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding the boolean flag to `Form1`, add it to `DxOverlayEngine` and check the local boolean flag in the library's `Draw()` implementation to bypass the necessary lines when set to `false`.

Then add accessor methods to the library in addition to draw, for example

```
void SetDrawEnabled(bool enable)
bool GetDrawEnabled();
```

In C# you can use a public property to accomplish the same thing.

```
public bool DrawEnabled { get; set; }
```

When you click buttons on Form1, change the DrawEnabled state appropriately. Within SetDrawEnabled, call Draw() at the appropriate state transitions (invalidate).

One way to accomplish this is to just call Draw() directly every time DrawEnabled's value is set.

```
private bool _drawEnabled = false;
public bool DrawEnabled 
{
    get { return _drawEnabled; }
    set { _drawEnabled=value; Draw(); }
}
```

Comment: Mike could you look please on my question now i tried your solution but even if it's true i don't see the drawings/overlays.

Comment: You need to implement the DrawEnabled setter so that it invalidates the display and/or calls overlayengine.Draw(). Changing the DrawEnabled value has to result in Draw() getting called (either to redraw with the additional content when true - or to redraw without the content when false)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the method Draw in the click event handler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  overlayengine.Draw();
}
```

Hope this helpe you .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking, but since it sounds like you have referenced your DLL from your winforms project then you have source for both projects.

Why not just add an overload for the draw method that accepts a bool? Then call the original method from the overload.

And since your making the bool decision in the winform and then calling the draw method, why not just make the decision to call or not call the draw method from the form?

Or am I completely missing the point of this question?